# Spring MVC - Serving static content in java class

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, resources

i have a function in my spring project that sends an email.
Now i want to send png-image in that email.

```
helper.addInline("myLogo", new ClassPathResource("resources/static/image/logo-mail.png"));
```

My Question is: how can i serve that image file to my java class.
I tried to map the file to an url in my controller but that didn't work.
Thank you!
Greetings

Comment: Where is that file exactly located? And what is the problem you have.

Comment: the file is in the image folder and the image folder is in my static folder.

Comment: the problem is that i don't know how to navigate there from my java class file

Comment: and the image is not in my email

Comment: You still haven't answered the question and your question isn't quite clear. What is the EXACT path of that file. What do you mean from navigate to the class file?

Answer (score 0):

The question is how is you want to send image -inline probably as that is what your helper class is trying to do.

Ideally you should you use load image using this syntax

```
<img src="cid:imageName.png"></img>
```

Next question is how to get he image in the e-mail - right that is where your problem lies? I would suggest to combine the Spring JavaMailSender with the Spring Resource interface to load and store the image data in the generated e-mail.

1. Load the images as Resource object - assuming you have file as /images/logo.png. Using apache commons library here.

> ```
> InputStreamSource imageSource = new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/logo.png")))
> ```

2. The next step is to add the image to the MIME message as an attachment:

> ```
> JavaMailSender mailSender = new JavaMailSenderImpl();  // Or use Spring IoC to inject a pre-configured JavaMailSenderImpl
> MimeMessage mimeMessage = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
> MimeMessageHelper message = new MimeMessageHelper(mimeMessage, true, "UTF-8");
> // Add information to the message, such as subject, recipients, etc
> message.addInline("logo.png", imageSource);
> ```

The addInline() method of the MimeMessageHelper reads the byte data from the InputStreamSource and creates the inline MIME body part to hold the attachment. It also sets the content ID to the name provided by the first parameter. Now, all that’s left is to reference the image in our HTML body:

```
message.setText("<img src=\"cid:logo.png\"></img><div>My logo</div>", true);
```

Comment: thank you so far!
my only problem is that intellij says that it can not resolve the method "IOUtils.toByteArray".

Comment: i tried to import the one from apache and the one from sun.msc

Comment: Add this dependency in maven or in classpath  <dependency>
 <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
 <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
 <version>2.4</version>  The ref docs are https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/apidocs/org/apache/commons/io/IOUtils.html
</dependency>

Comment: thank you for your help so far!
message.addInline("logo.png", imageSource);

Comment: Do you have spring library in class path? It looks like it cant find org.springframework.mail.javamail.MimeMessageHelper class

Comment: yes i have the path. no, unfortunately it isn' working yet :(

Comment: helper.addInline("logo", new ClassPathResource("/images/logo.png"));
do you know why that isn't working? is the path wrong?

Comment: when i name the path, do i have to navigate out of the folders where the .java file is, before going into the resources folder?

Comment: Can you please check the path or relative path in your deloyable archive? Does the file exist?if yes then what is the relative path? Start with hard-coding the path & then try to get relative path.

Comment: i went another route and uploaded the image to my server and put the direkt link in the html img src.

Comment: helper.setText("<html><head></head><body><center><img src="https://mywebsite/logo.png"></img></center></body></html>);

Comment: Great..can you please accept and up-vote the answer now?

Answer (score 0):

I solve in a little different way:

```
public static final String LOGO_DIR="classpath:/static/images/icon64.png";
```

...

```
@Inject
private ApplicationContext context;
```

...

```
final Resource resource = context.getResource(EmailTemplateConstants.LOGO_DIR);
        InputStreamSource logoSource = new ByteArrayResource(IOUtils.toByteArray(resource.getInputStream()));
        message.addInline(EmailTemplateConstants.LOGO_NAME, logoSource,
                EmailTemplateConstants.LOGO_CONTENT_TYPE);
```